# Make it so certain characters can't be inserted into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, submit, character

This is the code I use for inserting the data:

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("host","username","password") or die("couldn't Connect!");
mysql_select_db("table") or die("couldn't find db");

if(isset($_POST['user'])){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vids (name, gname, glink, ylink, category, user) 
    VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['gname']."', '".$_POST['glink']."', '".$_POST['ylink']."', '".$_POST['category']."', '".$_POST['user']."' )");

}
```

This is the form:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='0'>
    <tr><td><b><center>Upload your vid!</center></b>
    <tr><td><b> video name:</b></td><td><input name='name' type='text' ></input></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b> youtube video code:</b></td><td><input name='ylink' type='text' value='' ></input><a href='help.php'><img src='help.png' /></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b> game name:</b></td><td><input name='gname' type='text' ></input></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b> game link:</b></td><td><input name='glink' type='text' value='http://' ></input></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b> Category:</b></td><td><select name='category'>
    <option>shooter</option>
    <option>adventure</option>
    <option>arcade</option>
    <option>racing</option>
    <option>puzzle</option>
    <option>strategy</option>
    <option>sports</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Submitting under:</td><td><input type='hidden' name='user' value="<?php echo "" . $_SESSION['username'] . "" ?>"><?php echo "" . $_SESSION['username'] . "" ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='hidden' name='reviewed' value='no'></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='submit' value='Submit' title='Submit content!'></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to make it so that certain characters, namely "<", ">", "/", and other characters that relate to javascript and other coding languages aren't inserted into my MySQL table.

Any help would be awesome, I'd like to fix this problem right now as hackers do sometimes submit javascript redirects that redirect to different websites.

Thanks

Comment: This is called "sanitising" or "escaping" your variables FYI :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). And use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL attacks on your database if you didn't enable magic quotes.

Comment: +1, but I think that `htmlspecialchars` should actually be used on the way *out* of the database, not the way *in*. A `<` in a database field is not harmful until you paste that field into an HTML page.

Comment: I agree with you, but a `'); DROP vids` or `"); DROP vids` will kill his entire database if he doesn't escape quotes. My preferred way was `DATA -> mysql_real_escape_string -> database -> htmlspecialchars/htmlentities or strip_tags -> html`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hopefully this will fix it.